# Homology of $S^{n} \bigcup\limits_{f}e^{2n}$ space

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Suppose $f: S^{2n-1}\to S^n$ a continuous and $X = S^{n} \bigcup\limits_{f}e^{2n},$ where $e^{2n}$ is $2n$-cell homeomorphic to the open $2n$-disk int$(D^{2n}).$

My question is why $H_k(X) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\mathbb{Z}&\mbox{if }k = 0, n,2n\\ 
0&\mbox{otherwise}.
\end{array}\right.$

Can you explain for me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the chain complex that calculates cellular homology, it has $0$ in all dimensions, except for $k = 0, n, 2n$, where it has a free group $\cong \mathbb{Z}$ generated by the corresponding cell. Such complex clearly has homology as above.

$$0 \to \mathop{\mathbb{Z}}_{2n} \to 0 \to \cdots \to 0 \to \mathop{\mathbb{Z}}_n \to 0 \to \cdots \to 0 \to \mathop{\mathbb{Z}}_0 \to 0$$

I assume $n > 1$. For $n = 1$ the claim is false: glue $D^2$ to the circle to obtain the projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^2$. The corresponding chain complex is
$$0 \to \mathop{\mathbb{Z}}_2 \xrightarrow{\times 2} \mathop{\mathbb{Z}}_1 \xrightarrow{0} \mathop{\mathbb{Z}}_0 \to 0$$

Comment: @ Alejo. Because $S^n = e^0\sqcup e^n$ so $X = e^0\sqcup e^n\sqcup e^{2n}$??

Comment: @longhoang Yes.

Comment: @ Alejo. why $S^2 = e^0 \sqcup e^0 \sqcup e^1 \sqcup e^1 \sqcup e^2 \sqcup e^2$?? I think that $S^2 = e^0\sqcup e^2$

Comment: @longhoang What is the question? You can take any cellular decomposition of the $n$-sphere, but the simplest one has one point and one $n$-cell.

Comment: @ Alejo. I would like to ask if $S^n = e^0\sqcup e^n$ then a CW-complex decomposition of $S^n$ is $S^n = \bigcup\limits_{k = 0}^{n}X^{(k)},$ where $X^{(0)} = e^0, X^{(n)} = S^n, X^{(1)}, \ldots, X^{(n-1)}$ are empty. I think that replace $X^{(n)} = S^n$ by  $X^{(n)} = e^n$??right or wrong?